# Format-List w/ No Headers

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am looking for a way to do the same thing as `Format-Table -HideTableHeaders`, except with `Format-List`, I have looked all around... but haven't found any solutions.

Background, I am importing the same csv over and over, but over time, new rows will be added. When they are, I am sending an email with the new information. Here are the various parts of the puzzle that I have come up with on my own:

```
##### send email-workorder.ps1 #####
$smtpServer = "smtp.acme.com"
$current = import-csv .\current.csv -Delimiter "|" -header 'WO#', 'WO Cat', 'EQ#', 'EQName', 'EQLoc', 'Remark', 'Date', 'Time', 'Requestor'
$master = import-csv .\master.csv -Delimiter "|" -header 'WO#', 'WO Cat', 'EQ#', 'EQName', 'EQLoc', 'Remark', 'Date', 'Time', 'Requestor'
$compared = Compare-Object $current $master -Property  "WO#" -PassThru |  Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | Select-Object 'EQName', 'EQLoc', 'Remark', 'Time' | Format-List | Out-String

if ($compared) {
# Send E-Mail
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

$msg.From = "workorder@acme.com"
$msg.To.Add("mechanic@acme.com")
$msg.Subject = "New WO Submitted"
$msg.Body = $compared

$smtp.Send($msg) }
```

Batch file that will call the powershell script:

```
##### email-workorder.bat #####
##### this will be called by a scheduled task, set to run every five minutes #####
cd c:\scripts
sqlcmd -E -S acme-workorder-server -d WORDERDB -i worec.sql -h-1 -o "current.csv" -W -s "|"
powershell.exe -command .\email-workorder.ps1
move /y current.csv master.csv
exit
```

The worec.sql file that is referenced in the batch file:

```
##### worec.sql #####
set nocount on;
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT top 1000 [WONUMB]
      ,[WORKCAT]
      ,[EQNUMB]
      ,[EQNAME]
      ,[EQLOC]
      ,[REMARK]
      ,CAST([DATEISSUED] As DATE) As DATEISSUED
      ,CAST([TIMEISSUED] As TIME(0)) As TIMEISSUED
      ,[REQUESTEDBY]
  FROM [WORDERDB].[dbo].[WHREC]
  WHERE ( WORKCAT = 'BRK' Or
        WORKCAT = 'SAF' Or
        WORKCAT = 'CPU' Or      
        WORKCAT = 'COR' ) And
        WOCLOSED = 'N'
  ORDER BY [WONUMB] desc ) x
  ORDER BY [WONUMB] asc
```

Right now the email it is sending out is something like this:

```
EQName : PREP           
EQLoc  : NULL
Remark : need blown bulbs replaced@checkers 
Time   : 16:40:00

EQName : LIFT TRUCK 9         
EQLoc  : PREP 
Remark : guard obstructing view and probe no
Time   : 17:57:00

EQName : WASHER #2            
EQLoc  : PREPARATION 
Remark : sat 1 has 2 leaks and sat 2 has 2 l
Time   : 22:38:00

EQName : FINISHING 
EQLoc  : NULL
Remark : Need to repair pump on first statio
Time   : 19:05:00

EQName : FINISHING  
EQLoc  : NULL
Remark : SKY BAR NEEDS CLEANING 
Time   : 13:12:00
```

Which is fine, except I would like to get rid of the headers on the left and just have the actual information. This will be sent via text message on hand-held radios, so I want to keep the message as minimal as possible. I would like to get rid of the Hh:mm:00 as well, but haven't been able to figure that out yet. (Programming is  not my thing and let me know if I need to go back and add additional comments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folded at pipes for readability:

```
$compared = Compare-Object $current $master -Property  "WO#" -PassThru |
Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} |
foreach {($_.EQName,$_.EQLoc,$_.Remark,$_.Time,"`n") | out-string}
```

Comment: Almost perfect. Would it be possible to have a empty line between each section? From powershell it is doing the linebreak, but in the email program it is only doing a space and the first letter. ` FINISHING  
NULL
SKY BAR NEEDS CLEANING AT CALENDER 
13:12:00
`

Comment: Just add a newline ("`n") to the array.

Comment: Yea, I figured that out before I got back on here. It's now doing a double newline. But it's good enough. Thanks for your help.